Why can the spin operator $\hat{S}_\theta $ be defined using $ \hat{S}_x $, $\hat{S}_y $, and $ \hat{S}_z $? How can this be properly derived?
I'm trying to understand the rationale behind the spin operator $ \hat{S}_\theta $ along any axis that makes an angle $ \theta $ with the z-axis in terms of the spin operators $ \hat{S}_x $, $ \hat{S}_y $, and $ \hat{S}_z $. Specifically, the operator is given by:
$ \hat{S}_\theta = \hat{S}_x \sin\theta + \hat{S}_z \cos\theta $
Given the Pauli matrices and their relation to the spin operators:
$ \hat{S}_x = \frac{\hbar}{2} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad \hat{S}_z = \frac{\hbar}{2} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} $
This leads to:
$ \hat{S}_\theta = \frac{\hbar}{2} \begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & -\cos\theta \end{pmatrix} $
Obviously this makes a lot of sense but I am struggling why you can just write it this way. Can this be clearly derived? I guess it has to do with constructing new axes $z', x'$ at an angle $\theta$ from the original and using the fact that the commutator has to hold for this new system and that the probabilities have to correspond to the frame $z, x$ etcetera.
However, I'm struggling to understand why this construction is valid. Why can we define the spin operator along any axis using a linear combination of $ \hat{S}_x $ and $ \hat{S}_z $? How do the properties and commutation relations of the spin operators ensure that this definition is mathematically and physically consistent?
Could someone explain the underlying principles that justify the use of this combination for defining $ \hat{S}_\theta $?
EDIT: for simplicity I am referring to a 2D system, because if I understand it fundamentally it seems not complicated to generalize it to 3D.

I think what you are referring to here is a special case. More generally, let $ \hat{r} $ be any unit vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then I would define:
$ \hat{S}_\hat{r} = \sum_i r_i \hat{S}_i $

Where did the claim that that operator is the correct operator come from? Also, there is more than one axis that makes an given angle $\theta$ with the z-axis, so this doesn't even specify a unique axis. Your claim at the end that you are "referring to a 2d system" is also unclear - what kind of "2d system"? The operator $S_\theta$ you've written down rotates around an axis in the x-z plane, but it's still a 3d rotation. In 2d, there would be no $S_x,S_y,S_z$ - in 2d there is only rotation around the axis perpendicular to the plane through origin, no need to specify an axis explicitly.

What you write is incorrect, if you really mean that it should work "for any axis" as you write. If the axis is the $y$-axis then you will certainly need:
$$ \hat{S}_\theta = \hat{S}_y = \frac{\hbar}{2} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -i \\ i & 0 \end{pmatrix}, $$
and that is not possible with the expression you give for $ \hat{S}_\theta$, which only works if the axis in in the $xz$-plane.
But perhaps that is in fact the case you want to focus on and the question is then meant as why the expression $\hat{S}_x \sin\theta + \hat{S}_z \cos\theta $ is in that case correct. For that you need some definition of what is the correct spin matrix for rotations around a given axis. Following the usual group theoretical reasoning, I think looking at infinitesimal rotations (over an angle $\omega$) around that axis has to be sufficient. So you need to prove
that such an infinitesimal rotation can be written as:
$$
R_\theta(\omega) =  \mathbb 1 + {\small \frac{i\omega}\hbar} \ \hat{S}_\theta + O(\omega^2)
 = \left[ \mathbb 1 + {\small \frac\omega2}
 \begin{pmatrix}  \cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & -\cos\theta \end{pmatrix} 
\right]
 + O(\omega^2)  \tag{1}
$$
Rotations in this space act on spinors, so you need to know first how a spinor actually transforms if rotated around this axis. You could do that, by first rotating the intended rotation axis back to the $z$-axis (from wherever it is pointing to in the $xz$-plane, by an angle $\theta$ around the $y$-axis), then applying the required rotation over angle $\omega$ but around the $z$-axis instead of the intended axis, and then do the inverse of the rotation of the first step:
$$
R_\theta(\omega) =   R_y(\theta)\ R_z(\omega)\ R_y(-\theta) =
\\[8pt]
=\begin{pmatrix}  \cos\frac\theta 2 & -\sin\frac\theta 2 \\ \sin\frac\theta 2 & \cos\frac\theta 2 \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}  e^{i\omega/2} &  0 \\ 0 & e^{-i\omega/2} \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}  \cos\frac\theta 2 & \sin\frac\theta 2 \\ -\sin\frac\theta 2 & \cos\frac\theta 2 \end{pmatrix} 
\\[18pt]
=\mathbb 1 + {\small \frac{i\omega}2}\begin{pmatrix}  \cos\frac\theta 2 & -\sin\frac\theta 2 \\ \sin\frac\theta 2 & \cos\frac\theta 2 \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}  1 &  0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}  \cos\frac\theta 2 & \sin\frac\theta 2 \\ -\sin\frac\theta 2 & \cos\frac\theta 2 \end{pmatrix}  + O(\omega^2),
$$
which will then straightforwardly give the required result $(1)$
with $\hat{S}_\theta$ as proposed in the question.
